# How to search with codes in React site

Tags: reactjs, search, binary-search-tree

I have this page link with ordering codes:

```
https://example.com/en/search-some-products?query=my-product-0-11
```

You can see I am passing my-product-0-11 in above URL (-0-11 is some codes) and when I hit for search it shows me no result and when I removed those codes and pass only my-product and it shows my product which has name My Product.

I want to show same product even I pass product name with: my-product-0-11.

Below is my code syntax:

```
const Results = connectStateResults(
    ({ searchState, searchResults, children }) =>
      searchResults && searchResults.nbHits !== 0 ? (
        children
      ) : (
        <div>No results have been found for {searchState.query}.</div>
      )
  );
```

When I search with my-product-0-11 it says: No results have been found for as you can also see in my code snippet above.